# Polymer: autocomplete & onblur, input field does not equal valid when it is

Tags: html, validation, autocomplete, polymer, onblur

**This may be a possible bug in Polymer**: If I type in an input that has been typed in before, a series of autocomplete values may come up. If I select one using the up/down arrow keys and pressing the Enter key, the element's invalid attribute does not change to false even though the input is valid, however, the input element is stylized as being valid without the red text/underline.

If I tab or click outside of the element (onblur) it does not cause the field to validate. If I click back inside or tab back into the field, backspace one letter and retype, the elements invalid attribute will be properly set.

This has been tested with a regular paper-input and gold-zip-input in Safari 8.0.7.

**Work around**: As a possible work around, I would like to disable autocomplete for certain input fields. I can't find any documentation to do this. The HTML5 autocomplete attribute has no effect. Is there any way to turn off autocomplete in Polymer?